# Tokenizing mathematical expression - how to know how many implicit multiplications were used?

Tags: c, regex, stack, tokenize, pcre

I have an interesting problem. I'm working on a program that will tokenize a mathematical expression, like in the following example:

`'(3+4)*sin(45)'` -> `['(', '3', '+', '4', ')', '*', 'sin', '(', '45', ')']`

The right hand side of that is a stack, and each element is a Token struct, which I add to while tokenizing. To `malloc()` the space for the stack, I do the following:

`stack_ptr = malloc(strlen(input_expression) * sizeof(struct Token))`

I did this on the assumption that if the expression was `3*4*5`, then every single character is a token. So I thought that it would be impossible for an expression to have more tokens than characters.
It seems, however, that I was wrong.

I recently added the ability to detect implicit multiplication shorthands. I do this by keeping track of both the current token and past token in iteration. If the current token is either a function or a left bracket, and the previous token was either a right bracket or number, I add in a multiplier token before I add the current token. An example of this is as follows:

`'3sin(45)'` -> `['3', '*', 'sin', '(', '45', ')']`, or `4(3+1)` -> `['4', '*', '(', '3', '+', '1'])`

I'm sure you get the picture. Anyway, as you might expect, the addition of new tokens causes problems. Mainly...well, look at the URL bar.

I'm guessing that my options are as follows:

1. choose some arbitrary multiplier for stack 'insurance room', e.g. `malloc(strlen(input_expression) * 2 * sizeof(struct Token))`
2. implement some really irritating regex solution to detect implicit multiplication and count occurances of it
3. disable implicit multiplication

or, the reason I ask: is there some fancier way of doing this? Also, if these were my only solutions, I'm likely to go with #1 due to wanting to keep implicit multiplication, and due to how annoying I found regexes to be in this language, even while using the 'modern' pcre2 library. So I'm also interested to know: is #1 considered to be 'bad practice'?

Comment: Fascinating question! How do you determine whether something is a "function"? Is there a pre-set list of function names, or is there some other way to tell?

Comment: One option is to use a dynamic stack structure rather than a fixed size array. For example, a linked list. Or you could allocate in fixed size chunks and `realloc` as needed. Either way, suggest the code should not allocate based on `input_expression`. Write a "Stack" module which abstracts that away and only has `push` and `pop` operations. Internally the module handles dynamically adding nodes and/or any reallocs.

Comment: @NickReed Pretty much just a set list of functions, yeah. It's just a regex with 6 of the common ones I want to support, separated by pipes: `(sin|cos|tan|ln|exp|log)`

Comment: @kaylum I have actually written by own stack module, so I suppose making that dynamically allocate would be an option. How would you go about doing something like that? (the answer to that is probably more suited as a dedicated response)

Comment: Picking a linked list as a simple example - just allocate a new node every time `push` is called and link it at the front of the existing list. Also, what I really meant with the module comment is that the module should handle arbitrary number of nodes (ie any expression length) and thus should not allocated memory based on expression length.

Comment: I'm throwing in my endorsement of @kaylum's solution - a dynamic approach such as linked lists is going to afford you a lot more flexibility when it comes to things like this, and also doesn't run the issue of you allocating too much memory. A regex to find implicit multiplications shouldn't be hard to do, though! I'll try putting together a few test cases, and we'll see what comes out of it.

Comment: @lordnoob turns out that for your given criteria, a regex is not too irritating to implement! `(?<=\d|\))()(?=(?:sin|cos|tan|ln|exp|log)|\()` meets all your requirements, placing a zero-length capture group at the spot of each implicit multiplication. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QD5dnk/1/)

Comment: At this stage in the project, I don't think I want to go to the effort of changing the Stack type to use dynamic memory allocation - and using too much memory isn't a concern since if I fudge it (alloc 1.3*strlen, for example) it's only a couple hundred more bytes of memory allocated versus the 'perfect' solution - and this is only done once for every run of the program. It doesn't necessarily matter what I did, though, because both answers provided in the comments here were perfectly adequate, so I'm happy to accept either if they're posted as a standalone answer.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're tokenizing a mathematical expression and placing the tokens onto a stack. What are you going to do with that stack once you've created it?

Comment: @JimMischel Sorry for the late reply. I've finished this project now, but it was to perform shunting-yard on them to convert to RPN and then evaluate this (for a trapezium rule calculator). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm